# Chunked Transfer Encoding, Content-Length, and Byte Serving

Tags: http, streaming, chunked-encoding, http-chunked

In https://gist.github.com/CMCDragonkai/6bfade6431e9ffb7fe88, it says

> Do note that byte serving is compatible with chunked encoding, this
> would be applicable where you know the total content length, want to
> allow partial or resumable downloads, but you want to stream each
> partial response to the client.

I thought that if you want to allow partial and resumable downloads, you need to use the `Content-Length` HTTP header which is not allowed with chunked encoding.  Is my understanding incorrect?

Comment: For pause/resume you need `Range` request support. The range end is optional, you can request a range from a known position to the end of the content withtout the need to know the latter, like so `Range: 123-`.

Comment: @aergistal, OK, but I was asking about the Content-Length and Transfer-Encoding headers.

Comment: You don't need the Content-Length header, as previously mentioned you can request a range to the end of the source content.